# Returning two dates based on input

Tags: sql, datetime, sql-server, t-sql

I created a function that will return 2 dates that depend on an input parameter.

When the parameter is:

- 1  - return start date of current week and end date of current week
- 2  - return start date of last week and end date of last week
- 3  - return start date of current month and end date of current month
- 4  - return start date of last month and end date of last month

Could you please suggest improvements? And what name would be more appropriate for this function?

```
CREATE FUNCTION [ufn_GetRangeOfDates] 
( @Type int
)
RETURNS @Result TABLE     
( StartDate date
, EndDate date
)
AS
BEGIN

  declare @Today date = GetDate()

  -- current weak
  declare @CurrentWeakStart date = dateadd(day, 1-datepart(dw, @Today), CONVERT(date, @Today))
  declare @CurrentWeakEnd date = dateadd(day, 7-datepart(dw,  @Today), CONVERT(date,  @Today))
  -- last week
  declare @LastWeakStart date = DATEADD(dd, DATEPART(DW,@Today)*-1-6, @Today)
  declare @LastWeakEnd date =DATEADD(dd, DATEPART(DW,@Today)*-1, @Today)
  --current month
  declare @CurrentMonthStart date = DateAdd( day, 1 - Day( @Today ), @Today )
  declare @CurrentMonthEnd Date = DateAdd( day, -1, DateAdd( month, 1, @CurrentMonthStart ) )
  -- last month
  declare @LastMonthStart date = DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, @Today)-1, 0)
  declare @LastMonthEnd date = DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, -1, @Today)-1, -1)

  insert into @Result
  select CASE @Type
           WHEN 1 THEN @CurrentWeakStart
           WHEN 2 THEN @LastWeakStart
           WHEN 3 THEN @CurrentMonthStart
           WHEN 4 THEN @LastMonthStart
           ELSE NULL
         END
  ,      CASE @Type
           WHEN 1 THEN @CurrentWeakEnd
           WHEN 2 THEN @LastWeakEnd
           WHEN 3 THEN @CurrentMonthEnd
           WHEN 4 THEN @LastMonthEnd
           ELSE NULL
         END
  RETURN
END -- End of ufn_GetRangeOfDates
```

Comment: That's a good idea!

Comment: @Phrancis Thanks a lot. What about name?

Comment: I'll try to do a review soon. I write SQL all day long so I think I might have a few ideas.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Misspellings

There are several misspelled words you should correct (see line comments):

```
  -- current weak -- should be 'week'
  declare @CurrentWeakStart date = dateadd(day, 1-datepart(dw, @Today), CONVERT(date, @Today)) -- should be '@CurrentWeekStart'
  declare @CurrentWeakEnd date = dateadd(day, 7-datepart(dw,  @Today), CONVERT(date,  @Today)) --should be '@CurrentWeekEnd'
  -- last week
  declare @LastWeakStart date = DATEADD(dd, DATEPART(DW,@Today)*-1-6, @Today) -- should be '@LastWeekStart'
  declare @LastWeakEnd date =DATEADD(dd, DATEPART(DW,@Today)*-1, @Today) -- should be '@LastWeekEnd'
```

---

#### Magic numbers

You use `int`s 1,2,3,4 as codes but no indication of what they mean. I'd suggest to take a moment to declare them and give them meaningful name:

```
declare @StartAndEndOfCurrentWeek  int = 1;
declare @StartAndEndOfLastWeek     int = 2;
declare @StartAndEndOfCurrentMonth int = 3;
declare @StartAndEndOfLastMonth    int = 4;
```

Then this becomes more clear:

```
  insert into @Result
  select CASE @Type
           WHEN @StartAndEndOfCurrentWeek  THEN @CurrentWeekStart
           WHEN @StartAndEndOfLastWeek     THEN @LastWeekStart
           WHEN @StartAndEndOfCurrentMonth THEN @CurrentMonthStart
           WHEN @StartAndEndOfLastMonth    THEN @LastMonthStart
           ELSE NULL
         END
  ,      CASE @Type
           WHEN @StartAndEndOfCurrentWeek  THEN @CurrentWeekEnd
           WHEN @StartAndEndOfLastWeek     THEN @LastWeekEnd
           WHEN @StartAndEndOfCurrentMonth THEN @CurrentMonthEnd
           WHEN @StartAndEndOfLastMonth    THEN @LastMonthEnd
           ELSE NULL
         END
  RETURN
```

---

#### Capitalization

You should try to stick to one style of capitalization throughout for keywords. It makes it easier to read and less distracting. This is especially true of something that could have some other code mixed it, for example this one could look like there is some VBA:

> ```
> DateAdd( day, 1 - Day( @Today ), @Today )
> ```

What's the difference between `day` and `Day`? Well of course there isn't in SQL, but just the fact that it's capitalized differently may throw someone off that is less used to SQL and more to programming where capitalization makes a difference.

---

#### Overall

I think in general this is a good idea and seems like a useful function to have around. Especially if you work with finance stuff a lot. I think it could reasonably be broken into two functions though, one for week and one for month. Picture something like:

- `udf_getRangeOfDatesInWeek`
- `udf_getRangeOfDatesInMonth`

Then you only need to supply them an `int` parameter and put that in your `datediff()` operation. `0` for current, `-1` for last, `1` for next, etc. I think that would be much more flexible and useful!

Comment: All very good points, although I would probably keep the "magic numbers", and the reason is I would try to convert the function into an inline one and of course you can't declare variables in an inline TVF. But that doesn't matter much, because if you split the function into two, as you are suggesting at the end of your answer (which is a gold suggestion IMHO), you would avoid having magic numbers in the first place.